# Is it possible to change the ownership of an executable to root using sudo?

Tags: sudo, root, chown

I have an executable created by my userid that I need to have run as root.  Therefore I need to change the ownership of my executable to be root:root and use setuid.  When I attempt

```
sudo chown root:root [EXE_NAME]
```

I get the error:

```
chown: changing ownership of `[EXE_NAME]`: Operation not permitted
```

My constraints are:

- I have sudo ALL ALL for my userid in the sudoers file, but cannot login as root
- The executable that needs to run as root is attempting to bind to a network interface (hence the need to run as root) in promiscious mode using the pcap_open_live function.

Is there a better way to solve my ultimate problem, that is, needing to run an executable that binds to a network interface that is secure and does not require sudo or creating a root owned shell (`sudo tcsh`)

Comment: Which OS are you using? BSD? OSX, GNU/Linux?

Comment: GNU/Linux RHEL 6.2

Comment: See @Dennis's answer: if the file is on a filesystem that doesn't support ownership (like vfat or smb), then you can't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `sudo` actually gives you UID 0 (check with `sudo id`) I'd suspect that the file reside on a filesystem that doesn't support permissions (e.g. FAT32). On such a filesystem you cannot change ownership (or permissions) of a file.

Comment: `sudo id` gives UID 0.  How would I check the filesystem that the exe resides on?  (It is a net mount, I believe)

Comment: `mount` will list all mounted filesystems including their type. If it's a network-mounted filesystem, it's possible that root doesn't have write access to that filesystem (e.g. an NFS mount with `root_squash` enabled).

Comment: How do I tell if `root_squash` is enabled. Here is the output from `mount` `/home/sw/ type nfs (rw,sloppy,addr=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)` The IP is actually specified, I just figure its not relevant.

Comment: You take a look at `/etc/exports` on the NFS *server*. If the exported filesystem does not have the option `no_root_squash` set, then root sqashing is enabled (i.e. `root` is mapped to another account, usually `nobody`).

Comment: So I did eventually settle that the issue was that the exported file system did have root squashing enabled and I was unable to proceed as I wanted.  I also ended up with another job and this became someone else's problem.  Sorry this item took me nearly three years to get back to this.

Answer (score 1):

If your file system supports ownership, there are three more reasons I can think of:

1. The partition is mounted read-only.

   Try renaming the file or creating another file in the same directory. If you can, that's not the problem.
2. The file is locked.

   Check if the program is running. Try renaming the file.
3. The file is set as **append only** or **immutable**.

   To change this, execute the following command:

   ```
   sudo chattr -ai filename
   ```

Comment: Item 1 and 2. Check able to rename the file. Item 3: `lsattr [EXE_NAME]` gives error: `lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on [EXE_NAME]`

Comment: If the filesystem were mounted read-only, `chown` would report `Read-only file system`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change **ownership** (and not ownership and the group) then you can use `chown root filename`.  Prefixed by sudo if you are not root.

If you also want to change the group there is always `chgrp`.

(Granted, not as nice as all in a single command).

Comment: `sudo chown root filename` as you suggest produces the same error

Comment: @Hennes: `chown root:root filename` changes both owner and group.

Comment: Aye. But I just tried that as root and I got an error for `chown root:root filename` but not on `chown root filename`. (This was as root on a FFS filesystem on FreeBSD 7).

Answer (score 0):

Normal users can also bind to a network interface, just not to ports under 1024. Thus, you could have your program bind to a port >= 1024 and then redirect to that port either externally or via `ssh -fN -L 0.0.0.0:<PRIV_PORT>:localhost:<UNPRIV_PORT>`.

That being said, your problem could also relate to SElinux, which is enabled by default in RHEL. To disable it, set `SELINUX=disabled` in `/etc/selinux/config`.

Comment: I am binding to a port greater than 1024 and SELINUX is disabled.

Comment: So there's no need to run as root, or is there? If you can run `nc -l <PORTNUM>` without problems, then all should be fine and you don't need to run the program as root.

Comment: the issue is using pcap to monitor the traffic on a device, using `pcap_open_live` in promiscious mode.  When not ran as root: I receive the message: `eth0: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)'